# Can I disable Sliver Overlord's abilities with Pithing Needle?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I was looking through different cards to try and find something to counteract my dad's [Sliver Overlord](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSliver%20Overlord%5d) aside from directly killing or exiling it, and when I initially saw [Pithing Needle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPithing%20Needle%5d) I got really excited, but then I saw it didn't target mana abilities, which kind of renders it useless against the Overlord.

Is there a card that does target mana abilities, or will I just have to exile/destroy his Overlord?

Comment: You have an extremely low chance to draw a specific card on a Commander deck. You're playing green, so your artifact search abilities are further limited. I dunno how effective this card would be, unless you went blue.

Comment: @CyberClaw my deck is a hyper-draw deck so I will be able to get through my deck fairly fast to get to specific cards, and if not I have a couple cards that let me search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sliver Overlord's abilities are not mana abilities. Mana abilities are abilities that *produce* mana, like the ability on [Sylvan Caryatid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSylvan%20Caryatid%5d). (There are a few restrictions; not *everything* that produces mana is a mana ability. See [rule 605.1](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Mana_ability) if you're curious.)

Sliver Overlord's abilities are simple activated abilities, with mana in their *cost*. Pithing Needle will work just fine against them, as will anything else that prevents abilities from being activated (e.g. [Arrest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArrest%5d)), and anything that makes it lose abilities (e.g. [Lignify](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLignify%5d)).

Comment: That makes more sense. I thought it was weird it would only target abilities that don't cost mana.