# Would Loyalty Abilities be negated by Pithing Needle?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In doing research on how to counter activated abilities (See [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/33053/how-to-prevent-mana-activated-abilities)) I found the [Pithing Needle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPithing%20Needle%5d) and I wondered: do Loyalty Abilities count within the activated abilities targeted by Pithing Needle's text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pithing Needle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPithing%20Needle%5d) would *always* nullify the planeswalker's loyalty abilities.

According to rule 306.5d of the November 11, 2016 edition of the Magic: The Gathering Comprehensive Rules, loyalty abilities are activated abilities that (typically) do not produce mana.

> 306.5d Each planeswalker has a number of loyalty abilities, **which are activated abilities with
>   loyalty symbols in their costs**. Loyalty abilities follow special rules: A player may activate a
>   loyalty ability of a permanent he or she controls any time he or she has priority and the stack is
>   empty during a main phase of his or her turn, but only if none of that permanent’s loyalty
>   abilities have been activated that turn. See rule 606, “Loyalty Abilities.”

And this is echoed in rule 606.2 of the same compendium.

> 606.2. **An activated ability with a loyalty symbol in its cost is a loyalty ability.** Normally, only
>   planeswalkers have loyalty abilities

Additionally, as Jefromi pointed out, loyalty abilities are never mana abilities according to rule 605.1a

> 605.1a An activated ability is a mana ability if it meets all of the following criteria: it doesn’t have a
>   target, it could put mana into a player’s mana pool when it resolves, ***and* it’s not a loyalty
>   ability.** (See rule 606, “Loyalty Abilities.”)

Comment: Clarification: a "mana ability" is a specific kind of ability that _generates_ mana, not one that costs mana (there are additional restrictions as well).

Comment: The restrictions on mana abilities explicitly include this: "605.1a An activated ability is a mana ability if it meets all of the following criteria: it doesn’t have a target, it could put mana into a player’s mana pool when it resolves, and **it’s not a loyalty ability**. (See rule 606, “Loyalty Abilities.”)" There are loyalty abilities that produce mana, like [Chandra, Torch of Defiance](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=417683) or [Xenagos, the Reveler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373502) but they're not mana abilities.

Comment: I'm confused how you reached that final conclusion. Loyalty abilities, as you said, are definitely activated abilities, just a special kind that planeswalkers have. And they're never mana abilities, so Pithing Needle will always work on them.

Comment: @Jefromi I've been up for 14 hours, and apparently it shows. ;P